# Regex with comma separated numbers in Apex

Tags: regex, oracle-apex

As a preface, I realize there are other topics on regular expressions with comma separated numbers, but when I tried to use those solutions, they didn't work.

Basically, I am trying to create a regular expression to recognize comma separated numbers (in this case without spaces). Before trying to convert this into actual regex syntax, I realize that it should probably work something like this, where 'd' is a number and ',' is a comma, and '+' is a kleene plus:

```
((d+),)*(d+)
```

or

```
(d+)(,(d+))*
```

Here's the code I am using in an Apex validation to make sure that a certain field is a list of numbers separated by commas without spaces (note: I have tried several variations of this to no avail, but will only post one):

```
(\d+,)*(\d+)
```

For some reason this isn't working, but it seems to be the correct syntax of any digit 1 or more times followed by a single comma, and that entire expression can be repeated 0 or more times, and that entire repeated expression should always be followed by at least 1 digit.

This expression in practice does recognize all the accepted forms (ex: 100 or 100,200 etc.), but for some reason it also accepts answers like

```
'100,200,'
```

or

```
'100,200,,'
```

or

```
'100,,200'
```

I'm pretty stumped as to why this won't work as well as the previously given solutions which seem to do the same thing mine do. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: maybe something like: `^(\d+,)*\d+$` .. ok I'm sorry you already wrote exactly the same expression on your question. You may try using the anchors like I did `^$` and see what happens. Anyway it's really strange the behaviour you got. I realized now the anchors will make the difference because they will force the whole string to match the pattern not just a small part. And please avoid using look around as someone suggested.

Comment: I don't know why indicating that it's the beginning and end of a line would make that regular expression work, but it did for some reason! Thanks! Also, I'm not exactly what you mean by avoid using look around. Could you clarify?

Comment: previously it worked for string like "100,200,," because actually it  contains(!) the match in the first part "100,200". If you use the anchors you are telling the match has to represent the whole string not just a part. For look around I was wrong...actually I misunderstood ..sorry.

Comment: @Diego You can add your comment as answer. It seems to be what the OP wants and he can accept your answer.

Comment: ok I did it right now. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's it:

```
^(\d+,)*\d+$
```

The anchors `^$` will make the difference because they will force the whole string (not just a part) to match the pattern

Answer (score 2):

You should try pattern like this:

```
^(?:(\d+),)+(\d)+$
```